# sum of digits of numbers of the form $360\cdot2^{-k}$

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

One full turn around the circle is a 360 degrees turn. I have seen several posts on this forum concerning this value: "Why is the circle 360 degrees and not 'X' degrees". I see multiple answers saying that it is divisible by plenty of integers or that it is derived from a base-60 system.

But here is my question to you. Is this random?

360   -> 3 + 6 + 0 = 9

180   -> 1 + 8 + 0 = 9

90    -> 9 + 0 = 9

45    -> 4 + 5 = 9

22.5  -> 2 + 2 + 5 = 9

11.25 -> 1 + 1 + 2 + 5 = 9

If you're missing what I'm doing: I'm just cutting the circle in halves and adding the sum of the digits in the number as I continue.

Comment: Why did you stop? 5.625 -> 5+6+2+5=18, oh that's why (ok, you might repeat, 1+8=9). But seriously, this observation covers little more than the fact that 360 is a multiple of 9

Comment: That's because 360 is a multiple of 9.  Nothing more.  Nothing less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in mathematics happens purely by chance. Everything happens for a reason. The reason that you are seeing the digit sum of those numbers all equaling $9$ is because they are written in base-$10$. Generally, numbers divisible by $b-1$ written in base $b$ have a digit sum that is still divisible by $b-1$. This also works for (non-trivial) factors of $b-1$ (if any). Try out various numbers divisible by $9$ or, by $3$, and see for yourself. It's also not that hard to prove the general result with a little modular arithmetic. (It's related to Fermat's Little Theorem, if memory serves, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: I only learned of this because I got curious as to the reasons behind the length of repeating decimals for fractions. The final result provides a complete answer to the question: how long will the repeating decimal of $m/n$ be in base $b$? Getting there is a rather fascinating foray into elementary number theory.

Comment: Calculus is difficult enough for my brain, number theory would be a dream come true tho...

Comment: I don't think it's related to fermat's little theorem.  It's because $9 = 10 - 1$, $10^k - 1 = 9999999...= 9*111111$ and so if $abcd = a*1000 + b*100 + c*10 + d = (a+b+c+d) + 9(111a + 11b + c)$  So $abcd$ is a multiple of 9 if and only if $a + b+ c+d$ is also a multiple of $9$.  If that's too subtle:  If $abcd$ is such that $a+b+c+d = 9k$ then $abcd + 9 = abcd + 10 - 1 = ab(c+1)(d-1)$ and so $a + b + (c+1) + (d-1) =9$ as well if $c < 9$ and $d > 0$.  If $c =9$ or $d =0$ we get the same result but with carrying.  Do that multiple times and you get the result.

Comment: I was recalling how Fermat's little theorem proves the following: The repeating decimal, $1/p$ in base $b$ coprime to $p$ has length equal to a divisor of $p-1$, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not random.

---

> Definitions: The digit sum in base $10$ of a nonnegative rational number $x$ which I will denote as $\text{ds}(x)$ is the sum of the decimal digits of the number. The digit root of a nonnegative number, $\text{dr}(x)$ is the number you get when you take the repeated digit sum until a single digit is achieved, this is [achievable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) by the fact that $x_0+...+x_n \leq x_0+....10^n x_n$. As shown by Wiki (scroll to formal definition, and "Proof that a constant value exists".

**Theorem**

The digit root of positive multiples of $9$ in base ten is $9$

**Proof**

In base $10$ we have $x=x_0+10x_1+....+10^n x_n$ for some digits $x_i$ and any positive integer $x$. We may rewrite $x=(x_0+...x_n)+9x_0+99x_1+...(10^n-1)x_n$. Then if the positive integer $x$ is divisible by $9$ we must have that $x_0+...x_n=\text{ds}(x)$ is divisible by $9$. Then $\text{ds}(\text{ds}(x))=\text{ds}^2(x)$ must be divisible by $9$. And so must $\text{ds}^{n}(x)$. Hence the digit root is divisible by $9$. The only positive single digit number divisible by $9$ is $9$.

---

**Use**

Add zero digits to the end of your number or shift over the decimal by multiplying by $10^k$. This will not affect your digit sum and hence not effect your digit root.

$$\text{dr}(\frac{360}{2^k})=\text{dr}(\frac{360}{2^k} 10^k)=\text{dr}(360(5^k))$$

If $k \geq 0$ and is an integer, by the theorem above we must have $\text{dr}(\frac{360}{2^k})=9$ as $360(5^k)=9(40)5^k$ is divisible by $9$ and positive. On the other hand, if $k \leq 0$ then it is clear from the start that $360(2^{-k})$ is divisible by $9$ and positive.

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing is the explanation I had in the 3rd grade is a lot harder and more complicated than the one I had as a math major.

If $9 = 9;$ $9+9 = 18$ and $1+8 = 9$; $18 + 9 = 27$ and $2+7 = 9$.

We can do this for ever because...

If $abcd..... xyz; a+b+c+d+...... + x + y+ z = 9*N$ then $abcd.....xyz+ 9=abcd...xyz + 10 - 1$.  If $z > 0; y< 9$ this is $abcd....x(y+1)(z-1)$ and $a+b+c+d+..... + x + (y+1)+(z-1) = 9N$.

$z = 0$ then $abcd.....xy0 + 9 = abcd....xy9$ and $a+b+c+d+....+x+y+9 = 9*N + 1 = 9(N+1)$.

$z > 1$ and $w...y = 9$ then $abcd.....tuv99....9z + 9 = abcd.....tuv99....9z + 10 - 1 = abcd..... tu(v+1)000.....0(z-1)$ and $a+b+c+d + ..... +(v+1) + 0+0+0+....+0 +(z-1) = 9*N - 9-9-9-9-9-....9 = 9(N - k)$.

So the sum of all the digits of a multiple of 9 is a multiple of 9.

That was the 3rd grade proof.

... Math Major proof.

Let $N = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k10^k; a_k=0...9;$ be a decimal expansion. Let $m = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_i$ be the sum of its digits.

$N = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k10^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k(10^k-1) + \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_i = V + m$ where $V = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k(10^k-1)$.

Now $\frac {10^k -1}{10-1}=\frac {999....}{9} = 111111.... = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}10^i$ so $10^k -1 = 9*(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}10^i)$ is a multiple of $9$.  So each $a_k(10^k -1)$ is a multiple of $9$ so $V = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k(10^k-1)$ is a multiple of $9$.

So $N = V+m$ is a multiple of $9$ if and only if $m$, the sum of the digits of $N$,  is a multiple of $9$.